# How to use the sample data files on Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google Colab comes with some sample data files. I am using the file path of the file I want to use and trying to access it with pandas.

`pandas.read_csv('content/sample_data/mnist_test.csv')` keeps giving me this error:

`FileNotFoundError: File b'content/sample_data/mnist_test.csv' does not exist`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your current folder in google-colab is `/content`. You can either use
`pandas.read_csv('sample_data/mnist_test.csv')`

or
`pandas.read_csv('/content/sample_data/mnist_test.csv')`

Answer (score 1):

The path is given by Colab as `content/sample_data/mnist_test.csv`

Instead of using the whole path, removing the `content/` and using only `sample_data/mnist_test.csv` as the path works fine.

This works:

`pandas.read_csv('sample_data/mnist_test.csv')`